# How to change the font family when user language changes from english to hebrew

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an input field and I want to be able to detect the language that the user is typing with, and then change the font depending on whether the text is in English or Hebrew.
How can I do this?

How would this be handled if the user is typing in a combination of the two languages?

Comment: `what if he combines languages?` Questions like this are 'business' questions. They're requirements you have to establish first before even attempting to technically implement it. We can't answer that. I don't even know anything about the app in which this input resides.

Comment: How about creating a new font. Copy the ASCII characters from the English font you want and the other characters from the Hebrew font. Use the result as a webfont. Then you will have no need to check while the user is typing.

Comment: @MrLister how can i do this?

Comment: Use a font editor. There are lots of free font editors available.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of how to handle the actual language detection bit, but as far as changing the font-family you could set up two different classes, one for each language:

```
.english {
    font-family: "first font";
}

.hebrew{
    font-family: "second font";
}
```

From there, depending on which language is being used, you can use jquery to add and remove these classes from your input field such as:

```
$("#myinput").addClass("english");
$("#myinput").removeClass("hebrew");
```

In my own personal opinion real-time language detection may be a very hard thing to accomplish. However, you may consider using regex to determine the language. If the string of characters that the user entered matches any part of the alphabet of either language, then you will know which language it is in. Having a regex for each language will allow you to detect if both languages were used also. If both alphabets match to the string then you will know that a combination was used. Your regex would look something like this:

```
var english= new RegExp('^[abcdefg.....XYZ]+$');
//Fill in the whole alphabet however

    if (english.test(MYINPUTSTRING)) {
        alert('This is english');
    } else {
        alert('This is not english');
    }
```

Comment: and if combining how can i put each word in the same input in different fonts?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only set the font for the entire input tag not each individual word. If you want to set the font for individual words you would have to take the input text and place it somewhere else on the screen and then use 'span's to add the language classes to each particular word